# How to post to Google Measurement Protocol using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

How can I hit Google Analytics events with a simple POST request of Google Measurement Protocol?

I can't (and don't want) use to use an external JavaScript library to get my job done.

My use case is to fire the events inside a Figma plugin. That's why I want a simple POST request solution.

Comment: You can add custom triggers to your google analytics. I'm assuming that's what you want to do

Comment: Yeah, that's my goal. However, the environment is a Figma plugin and not a web app. That's why I want a pure POST request solution

Comment: You can't login to the web based application to add these event listeners?

Comment: Basically, I want to track usage events e.g. how many users clicked a specific button. And the plugin doesn't communicate with the web app at all. Is that what you asked or have I misunderstood it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what sort of browser support you need. If it's modern browsers (post-Edge IE and others), you can send a [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) request:

```
const apiUrl = '/post/url';
const data = {};

fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: 'POST', 
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
  .then(res => console.log("Response a success", res))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error caught', err));
```

Otherwise you need to run it through an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST, apiUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ data }));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Robert! I'm searching for a specific Google Analytics POST request though, not the generic approach on how to make API calls.

Comment: @dmraptis, do fetch request that mimics the hits built by analytics.js . What do you expect ? a full working example ?